# How can write PouchDB query with "like" as in SQL

Tags: pouchdb

In *SQL* I write

```
SELECT some FROM tbl WHERE name like '*abc*'
```

How can I write this in *PouchDB*?

Answer (score 1):

I use this solution:

```
var query = 'abc'.toLowerCase();
var result = [];
db.query('query_group/query_name')
  .then(function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
      if (data.rows[i].value.someField.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1 ) {
        result.push(data.rows[i].value);
      }
    }
  });
```